# A slot as a paramater in a lambda function in C++ / Qt

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, lambda, slot

I have a lambda method which I would like to receive a slot as a parameter

I have ended up with:

```
  auto createShortcuts = [ = ]( const QString &sequence, const std::function < void () > &slot  )
  {
    QShortcut *sc = new QShortcut( QKeySequence( sequence ), this );
    connect( sc, &QShortcut::activated, mMyObject, slot );
  };

  createShortcuts( QStringLiteral( "whatever" ), [=](){mMyObject->mySlot();} );
```

But I would prefer avoid using a lambda slot when calling createShortcuts. Rather something like

```
  auto createShortcuts = [ = ]( const QString &sequence, void ( MyObject::* )() )
  {
    QShortcut *sc = new QShortcut( QKeySequence( sequence ), this );
    connect( sc, &QShortcut::activated, mMyObject, ??? );
  };

  createShortcuts( QStringLiteral( "whatever" ), &MyObject::mySlot );
```

But I couldn't find the proper syntax to call the slot.

Comment: Capture what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, you're just missing the name of the function pointer.

```
  auto createShortcuts = [ = ]( const QString &sequence, void ( MyObject::* myFunc )() )
  {
    QShortcut *sc = new QShortcut( QKeySequence( sequence ), this );
    connect( sc, &QShortcut::activated, mMyObject, myFunc);
  };

  createShortcuts( QStringLiteral( "whatever" ), &MyObject::mySlot );
```

Edit:
The above solution works only if the `mMyObject` is declared in the same scope `createShortcuts` is declared, the below is safer.

```
  auto createShortcuts = [ = ]( const QString &sequence, const MyObject* mMyObject, void ( MyObject::* myFunc )() )
  {
    QShortcut *sc = new QShortcut( QKeySequence( sequence ), this );
    connect( sc, &QShortcut::activated, mMyObject, myFunc);
  };
  auto obj = new MyObject();
  createShortcuts( QStringLiteral( "whatever" ), obj, &MyObject::mySlot );
```

Comment: The object is already there from the context in this question (see `mMyObject`), but +1 for adding it this way to make things explicit for future readers.